# Android - как различить EditText?

Tags: android-textview, android, android-edittext, java

Здравствуйте! Прошу помочь в решении проблемы:

Что есть:

---

```
1 TextWatcher (mWatcher)
2 EditText (mSourceTitle и mSourceText)
2 TextView (mTitle и mText)
```

---

Потом я подключаю `EditText`'ы к одному `TextWatcher`'у. Проблема заключается в том, что мне надо как-то различить, из какого `EditText` пошёл ввод и в какой `TextView` направить текст. По задумке данные из `mSourceTitle` идут в `mTitle`, а из `mSourceText` в `mText`. Как можно решить эту проблему? Создавать 2 `TextWatcher`'a не вариант.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно и одним обойтись - [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702771/how-to-use-single-textwatcher-for-multiple-edittexts/6172024#6172024).

Comment: Так же как и с ClickListener